# Exact meaning of "Chagrin"

Tags: differences

What is the exact meaning of "chagrin"? Does it have a component of humiliation or that of disappointment?

Comment: Have you checked the dictionary meanings of the word?

Comment: Yes. But still I can't get hold of the exact idea of the word.

Comment: Tell us what you found and what about the definition you did not understand.  (If you don't we will close the question and you will be chagrined.)

Comment: Having consulted several good dictionaries , I come t understand the following: When I find something happening or having happened against my expectations, I am apt to be chagrined. When I make mistake or fail to do sth, "chagrin" is the word that would describe my mental state. But in the latter case "frustration" can also be used to describe my state of mind and in the former "disappointment" or "annoyance" can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

***Chagrin*** is a French word, usually translated into English as "despondency, grief, broken-heartedness etc" (Concise Oxford Hachette, French Dictionary).

It has long been adopted into English, the following being some examples from the OED:

> 1656   T. Blount Glossographia   Chagrin, cark, melancholy, heaviness,
>   anxiety, anguish of mind; also a disease coming by melancholy. 1656
>   A. Cowley Pindaric Odes in Wks. (1710) I. 236   There are who all
>   their Patients chagrin have, As if they took each morn worse Potions
>   than they gave. 1677   W. Temple Let. in Wks. (1731) II. 426   His
>   illness..derived, perhaps, from the Fatigue and Chagrin of his
>   Business. a1680   S. Butler Genuine Remains (1759) I. 121   For, if he
>   feel no Shagrin, or Remorse, His Forehead's shot-free, and he's ne'er
>   the worse. 1714   Pope Rape of Lock (new ed.) iv. 34   Hear me, and
>   touch Belinda with Chagrin; That single Act gives half the World the
>   Spleen. 1751   Johnson Rambler No. 181. ⁋7   I hid myself..in the
>   country, that my chagrin might fume away without observation. a1845
>   R. H. Barham Wedding-day in Ingoldsby Legends (1847) 3rd Ser. 210
>   Each Saturday night when devoured by chagrin, he Sits listening to

However the etymology is interesting, since the word itself, it would appear, arose metaphorically (Fr *chagrin* ENG *shagreen*) in the seventeenth century from the word meaning:

> 1a. A species of untanned leather with a rough granular surface,
>   prepared from the skin of the horse, ass, etc., or of the shark, seal,
>   etc., and frequently dyed green. Also, an imitation of this. (OED).

According to the OED the sense development from "rough untanned leather" to "despondency and grief" occurred in French, rather than in English.

*In strict answer to the question* the "non-leather" meanings given to it in English per the OED are as follows:

> 3. That which frets or worries the mind; fretting trouble, carking care, worry, anxiety; melancholy. Obsolete.
>
> 4 a. esp. Acute vexation, annoyance, or mortification, arising from
>   disappointment, thwarting, or failure.
>
> 4b. in plural. Troubles; vexations.

**No component of *humiliation* is included, neither in the Oxford French Hachette, nor in the OED. Though disappointment is clearly implied.**

Comment: Your first sentence is a little unclear – am I correct to think you mean that the translated meaning of the French word is ‘despondency’, etc., not that the meaning of the English word is those things? Because those definitions are all a good deal stronger than how I would define _chagrin_ in English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Good point. I will change "meaning" to "usually translated into English as". Those are the equivalent English words  which a reputable French to English dictionary assigns to the French word "chagrin".  If you are saying that when "chagrin" is used in English it means something different, you may possibly be right - though I am not saying you necessarily are. The OED meanings would suggest you may have a case.

Comment: Fretting, annoyance, worry, and vexation are definitely words I find more closely related to _chagrin_ than despondency, grief, or broken-heartedness. The humorous overtones of “much to sb’s chagrin”, the most common collocation with the word, has perhaps helped to make the word less intense in English than it is in French.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The Shorter OED, perhaps a more everyday dictionary, defines it as : *1. Worry, anxiety, melancholy 2. Mortification arising from disappointment or failure; acute vexation or annoyance. disappointment.* It does seem slightly less intense than *despondency* or *broken heartedness* - but one thing worth remembering here is perhaps that the French are rather more likely to give expression to their intense emotions than are the English, where the stiff upper-lip still rules to some extent. To me *chagrin* is quintessentially a French word.

Comment: Thank you WS2 for the detailed answer and all of you who cared to reply.